# Using the result of a previous cell to compute the value in the current cell for the same variable in r

Tags: r

I am working with a customer database. I would like to compute the value of a cell in a column called EAD1 by using the computed value of previous cell for the same EAD1 column.

An example below shows the data and expected result for EAD1 for data set called data1

```
Acc_Num, Record_count, BRD, Account_Balance, EAD1  
100, 1, 0.9, 100, 100
100, 2, 0.9, 100,  90  
100, 3, 0.9, 100,  81  
102, 1, 0.8, 100, 100  
102, 2, 0.8, 100,  80   

For Record_count = 1, EAD1 = Account_Balance  
For Record_count > 1, EAD1 = EAD1 previous cell * BRD
```

Comment: Have you read the online doc for `lag()`?  Should this calculation only be performed within the same `Acc_Num`?  What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: I have used the following code:  St2 <- St2 %>% mutate(
+   EAD1 := ifelse(Forecast_Horizon>1,  BRD * lag(EAD1), EAD1).  It did not work because it only computes correctly for record_count = 2

Comment: `Forecast_Horizon` does not appear in your sample data frame! `+ EAD1 :=` makes no sense.  Try `EAD1=`.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Same result. The calculation only runs for Record_count=2. For Record_count3 the result = 0

Comment: AND your data is not reproducible.  Lines 2, 3 and 5 have only four elements where five are required.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*. I give up.

Comment: My apologies for this. The data has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the `dplyr` package. I've recreated your data using the `tribble` function, but you won't need to worry about that, other than I've called the dataframe `plain_data`.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

plain_data <- tribble(~Acc_Num, ~Record_count, ~BRD, ~Account_Balance, ~EAD1,
100, 1, 0.9, 100, 100,
100, 2, 0.9, 100,  90,  
100, 3, 0.9, 100,  81,  
102, 1, 0.8, 100, 100,  
102, 2, 0.8, 100,  80)
```

Here's the solution with `dplyr` using the pipe operator. We use `mutate` to create a new column, called `new_column`. We use the `if_else` to make the operation conditional on whether the value for each particular row in `Record_count` is 1 or not. If the condition is met, `new_column` takes the value of `Account_Balance`, if not we use the `lag` function on the column `EAD1`, specifying the lag length to be 1 (denoting the previous row in data frame) and calculating that value with the current row's value of `BRD`.

```r
calculated_data <- plain_data %>% 
  mutate(new_column = if_else(
    condition = Record_count == 1,
    true = Account_Balance, # What gets calculated when Record_count is 1
    false = lag(EAD1, 1) * BRD) # What gets calculated when Record_count is NOT 1
  )

calculated_data
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   Acc_Num Record_count   BRD Account_Balance  EAD1 new_column
#>     <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     100            1   0.9             100   100        100
#> 2     100            2   0.9             100    90         90
#> 3     100            3   0.9             100    81         81
#> 4     102            1   0.8             100   100        100
#> 5     102            2   0.8             100    80         80
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Hope this helps. If not, let me know :)

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your help. Your code example assumes that EAD1 is populated. EAD1 should actually be the result of the calculation. Your code only works if EAD1 is populated. If EAD is not populated it does not work.